# Netty 4.0 - instanciate DefaultChannelGroup

Tags: netty

I am currently migrating my project from Netty 3.x to 4.0.4 Final and i have a little question about ChannelGroups.

DefaultChannelGroup needs now an EventExecutor in the constructor.
Unfortunately i didn´t really understand the thread model of Netty 4.0 yet.

How can i instanciate an EventExecutor for my ChannelGroups?
I just want the write operations beeing executed in several threads.

```
ChannelGroup newChannelGroup = 
new DefaultChannelGroup(name, new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1).next());
```

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that's used in the examples is:

```
ChannelGroup channelGroup = 
  new DefaultChannelGroup (name, GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: The doc says about GlobalEventExecutor: **Please note it is not scalable to schedule large number of tasks to this executor; use a dedicated executor.** Maybe there will be a large number of task in my case. So i think i need a dedicated one

Comment: It's easy enough to create a dedicated one, but the [docs](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.html) say that the group uses the "EventExecutor to notify the ChannelGroupFuture's", so I assume (but am not 100% sure) that it will be sufficient.